# Spring mvc - POST request with @ModelAttribute cause unnecessary sql queries

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I have a form with three select inputs, which are added from the db in the view. Everything is OK and the user can select for every select. The problem is that when I submit the form, the `@ModelAttribute` generates the same queries as the GET request (when these three selects are added into the view) and in the same, the select fields are empty after the POST.

```
@GetMapping("/road-assistance")
public String viewPage(Model model, Locale locale) {

    model.addAttribute("roadAssistanceDto", roadAssistanceService.createRoadAssistanceDto(locale, null));
    return "admin/roadassistance/view";
}



@PostMapping("/road-assistance")
public String createRoadAssistance(Model model, Locale locale,
                                   final @Valid @ModelAttribute("roadAssistanceDto") RoadAssistanceDto roadAssistanceDto,
                                   BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    return "admin/roadassistance/view";
}
```

Why the `@PostMapping` generates the same queries and in the same time, I don't have the info in the view/model?

the view -

```
<div class="row card-pagging">
        <div class="col-sm-2 mt-3 offset-sm-2">
            <label data-th-text="#{control.panel.roadassistance.country}" 
 class="control-label"
                   for="country">Country</label>
            <select id="country" data-th-field="*{country}" class="form-control">
                <option data-th-each="countryList : ${roadAssistanceDto.countryList}"
                        data-th-value="${countryList.id}"
                        data-th-text="${countryList.countryI18n[#locale].name}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
            <label data-th-text="#{control.panel.roadassistance.region}" class="control-label"
                   for="region">Region</label>
            <select data-th-field="*{region}" id="region" class="form-control">
                <option value='' data-th-text="#{control.panel.roadassistance.chooseregion}"></option>
                <option data-th-each="reg : ${roadAssistanceDto.regionList}" data-th-value="${reg.id}"
                        data-th-text="${reg.regionI18n[#locale].name}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 mt-3">
            <label data-th-text="#{control.panel.roadassistance.city}" class="control-label"
                   for="region">City</label>
            <select data-th-field="*{city}" id="city" class="form-control">
                <option value="" data-th-text="#{control.panel.roadassistance.chooseregion}"></option>
                <option data-th-each="city : ${roadAssistanceDto.cityList}" data-th-value="${city.id}"
                        data-th-text="${city.cityI18n[#locale].name}"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the RoadAssistanceDto -

```
public class RoadAssistanceDto implements Serializable {

private Long id;

private Country country;

private Region region;

private City city;

private List<Country> countryList;

private List<Region> regionList;

private List<City> cityList;

/* GETTERS AND SETTERS /*

}
```

Hm... I think that I notice the problem.. there is something workng when I'm binding the fields in the thymeleaf... but anyway, why is generating these queries?

Comment: Add some code of view (form)  please!

Comment: Add the code of roadAssistanceDto !

Comment: @DariushJafari Done

Comment: Can't you just set a breakpoint, and check the callstack and see why the call happens. Even if there was some documentation that explained exactly how `@ModelAttribute`, I would still preferere the debug approach - The code never lies :) Looking in the docs one possibility could be `"An @ModelAttribute on a method argument indicates the argument should be retrieved from the model. If not present in the model, the argument should be instantiated first and then added to the model."`